# NullPointerException in PrintWriter[] array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, nullpointerexception, printwriter

I have a problem which i am trying to figure out for days now.

Simple Code Overview(PseudoCode):

1 - When a user connects create a PrintWriter for him.

2 - Store the PrintWriter object into a PrintWriter[] array.

3 - Increment the number of users connected.

What is my problem?

- The compiler throws a NullPointerException

What caused the NPE?

- When the sendMessage() method is called by object created in the mainWindow class the PrintWriter array if empty, i don't know what is causing it to be empty since all the the variables and arrays have static modifiers and the PrintWriter[] array gets a value in the constuctor(when a user connects).
- Inside the ServerHandler constuctor when i try to send a message to the client it works fine and i can see that the PrintWriter[] array is not empty, but when i call the sendMessage() method from the mainWindow instance the array is empty and the userCounter integer variable is still 0.

What have i tried to fix it?

- Setting the variebles and the array modifiers to volatile and static.
- Writing all the code from scratch over and over again.

Server Class(works fine):

```
package homeControl;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Server{
String sporocilo = null;
int id = 0;

outputHelper o = new outputHelper();


public void sprejmiPovezavo()
{
    try
    {
        ServerSocket svrSock = new ServerSocket(5000);

        while(true){

        Socket klientSocket = svrSock.accept();


        new Thread(new ServerHandler(klientSocket)).start();

        }


    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


    public static void main(String[] args){
Server svr = new Server();
svr.sprejmiPovezavo();
}

}
```

ServerHandler class(this class causes the problems)

```
package homeControl;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ServerHandler implements Runnable{
static PrintWriter pw;
static PrintWriter[] writerHolder = new PrintWriter[10];
static int userCounter;
static int selectedID;


public ServerHandler(Socket socket){
    try{
        pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        writerHolder[userCounter] = pw;

        // Testing if this writerHolder[] can send the message to the client.
        writerHolder[userCounter].println("autoSent - Testint!");
        writerHolder[userCounter].flush();

        userCounter++;// Increment the number of people connected

        //Testing the values of the variables.
        System.out.println("ORG!\nuserCounter:" + userCounter +  "\nwriterHolder[userCounter]" + writerHolder[0]);
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public ServerHandler()
{
    // Empty constructor
    // Used so that i don't need to pass a Socket into the class when i create a ServerHandler object from the mainWindow.class...
}



public void sendMessage(int tempID, String messageToBeSent)
{   // Testing the values of variables at the time that this method gets called.
    System.out.println("tempID:" + tempID + "\n" + "messageToBeSent:" +       messageToBeSent + "\n" + "userCounter:" + userCounter + "\n" + "selectedID:" + selectedID); 
    // End of test/Actual code:
    writerHolder[tempID].println(messageToBeSent);
    writerHolder[tempID].flush();
}

public void run()
{

}

}
```

mainWindows class(where the sendMessage() method gets called)

```
package homeControl;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class mainWindow extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField messageTextField;

ServerHandler svr = new ServerHandler(); // Thats why i use the empty constuctor in ServerHandler.class.
outputHelper o = new outputHelper();
int ID;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mainWindow frame = new mainWindow();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public mainWindow() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnOptions = new JMenu("Options");
    menuBar.add(mnOptions);

    JMenu mnId = new JMenu("ID");
    menuBar.add(mnId);

    JMenuItem idEnaItem = new JMenuItem("ID: 0");
    mnId.add(idEnaItem);

    JMenuItem idDvaItem = new JMenuItem("ID: 1");
    mnId.add(idDvaItem);

    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    messageTextField = new JTextField();
    messageTextField.setBounds(10, 209, 292, 20);
    contentPane.add(messageTextField);
    messageTextField.setColumns(10);

    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.setBounds(312, 208, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(sendButton);
    sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            if(event.getActionCommand() != null)
            { // Calling the sendMessage() in the ServerHandler.class which should send a message to the Client.
               svr.sendMessage(ID,messageTextField.getText());
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Output from the ServerHandler constructor when i'm testing the PrintWriters:

ORG!

userCounter:1

writerHolder[userCounter]java.io.PrintWriter@798c668c

Ouput from the SendMessage method when i manualy try to send a message:

messageToBeSent:dsda

userCounter:0

selectedID:0

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at homeControl.ServerHandler.sendMessage(ServerHandler.java:45)
at homeControl.mainWindow$2.actionPerformed(mainWindow.java:84)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The *compiler* doesn't throw an exception. An exception is thrown at *execution* time, long after the compiler has completed. Beyond that, you've provided a huge amount of code - please try to cut it down to a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. Also, please give a full stack trace so we can see *where* the exception is being thrown.

Comment: You use a variable named ID to define which `PrintWriter` will be used. Where is it being set? I couldn't find it. You may be attempting to access a position in your array which might not have been set yet.

Comment: @MAuren Defaults to 0.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OK, but the way he/she exposes the problem makes me think it should be set to another value.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a newbie in java and programming in general.I pasted all the code so that all the viewers of this question can test it in their compilers.

Comment: i deleted the lines where i input the ID because the code pasted here is  already huge.

Comment: are you launching sprejmiPovezavo and mainWindow in paralell in different processes? (eg: different command line windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is the problem (in Server):

```
new Thread(new ServerHandler(klientSocket)).start();
```

Here you're creating a *new* `ServerHandler`. That's completely separate from the instance of `ServerHandler` which you're creating in `mainWindow`. So the one created by `Server` will end up with a populated `PrintWriter` array... and the one that you're creating in `mainWindow` will always have an array of null element values.

You should have *one* instance of `ServerHandler` which both `mainWindow` and `Server` share.

Comment: How do i create a instance of ServerHandler that both share?

Comment: @user2794550: I've just noticed that you've got two different `main` methods, so presumably you've actually got two entirely separate processes - how did you expect those to be sharing an array? You'd need to run *one* process. To be honest, it's not clear what you're trying to do in the first place...

Comment: I removed the main method from the mainWindow class and it worked no more NPE's and i can send messages to clients without a problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `mainWindow()` class, you have

```
ServerHandler svr = new ServerHandler(); // Thats why i use the empty constuctor in ServerHandler.class.
```

which calls the empty constructor which doesn't set any `PrintWriter` instances in the `PrintWriter[]`.

```
public ServerHandler()
{
    // you don't initialize any array elements
}
```

You then try to `sendMessage()` by accessing

```
writerHolder[tempID].println(messageToBeSent);
writerHolder[tempID].flush();
```

an unitialized element in the array, causing **NPE**.

---

Also, your `mainWindow` and `Server` classes are completely disjoint. There's no relation between them. Should there be?

Comment: I call this constructor because i don't want the main constructor to be called, because it needs a socket to be passed and i don't know how to create a instance of a class wihout calling the constuctor(if its possible).

Comment: @user2794550 You can't create an instance without a constructor call. How are you going to send a message if you don't have a socket to connect to?

Comment: I thought that this does not cause a problem because the i have static modifiers.

Comment: @user But you haven't ran the `Server` code do initialize them. Keep in mind order matters.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand what you are trying to say, could you paste some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start the mainWindow from server:

```
public void sprejmiPovezavo()
{
    try
    {
        ServerSocket svrSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
        MainWindow mainWindow frame = new mainWindow();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        while(true){

        Socket klientSocket = svrSock.accept();


        new Thread(new ServerHandler(klientSocket)).start();

        }


    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and launch server (sprejmiPovezavo) only, instead of launching mainWindow and the server (sprejmiPovezavo).

Comment: I tried the code above, however it still gives me a NullPointerException