# SocketException: Connection reset after reconnect

Tags: java, sockets, exception

If i start the Server first and then the Client everything works perfect, but when i start the client first and then the server(making sure that the Client is able to connect when the svr crashes and then goes online again) the Client does connect to the Server, but after 2,3 seconds it throws a SocketException: Connection reset. I don't know what is causing it and i would really apprechiate it if someone could help me figure this out.

Server code that handles the clients:

```
public ServerHandler(Socket socket){
    try{
        pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        writerHolder[userCounter] = pw;

        InputStreamReader in = new          InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(in);


        userCounter++;// Increment the number of people connected

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client code that connects to the Server:

```
    private  void startConnection()
{
    try
    {
        sock = new Socket("192.168.1.5", 5000);
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(input);
        pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected to the server!");

    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
        //timer.reconnectTimer(20);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at homeControl.ServerHandler.run(ServerHandler.java:52)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where is `ServerHandler.java:52`? Also, I don't see any `readLine` calls.

Comment: Who throws the exception, the server or the client?

Comment: @Pietu1998 This is just a code snippet.

Comment: @user2794550 Well OK, but how would you think we could debug your code if you don't post all of it, including the line that throws the exception?

Comment: @Pietu1998 - The code is basicly the same, only the main method was removed in the GUi class, but that doesn't matter in this case anyway.
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916832/nullpointerexception-in-printwriter-array-java/18917063?noredirect=1#comment27928420_18917063

Comment: @user2794550 You can't expect us to read your other questions. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself." EDIT: I went to your other question and _still_ couldn't find the problematic code.

Answer (score 1):

"Connection reset" usually means that the remote side closed its side of the socket without reading the data that you sent. Make sure that you read data sent to you before you close a socket.

Comment: To be honest, i don't close a socket at all, how should i do it? Thank s.

Comment: then the connection is closed by the os when the  program terminates, and if the program hadn't read the data sent to it the connection is reset